# AngularJS get related data from user through JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, api, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework, but question is about AngularJS. I have written json api on ruby on rails. For authentication I choose [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) + [devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth).

User json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "User1",
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "current-sign-in-at": "..",
      "last-sign-in-at": "..",
      "created-at": ".."
    },
    "relationships": {
      "friends": {
        "data": [
              {
                  "id": "2",
                  "type": "users"
              }
         ]
       }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "users",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "User2",
        "email": "user@user.com",
        "current-sign-in-at": "..",
        "last-sign-in-at": "..",
        "created-at": ".."
      },
      "relationships": {
        "friends": {
             "data": [ ]
         }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My serializer for user:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email,:current_sign_in_at,
              :last_sign_in_at, :created_at
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end
```

Current user object as response:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":1,"provider":"email","uid":"0a56bb6b-dc72-4ef3-906e-1c17cb2fef46","name"
:"User1","nickname":null,"image":null,"email":"email@email.com"}}
```

There is my problem, I can't reach user relationship information.

I don't know why, but object name in my view is user (not current_user) and don't have access for it in my controllers.
Question is how can I have some additional information from this object and how to provide current user object access for my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so the answer is really simple. ng-token-auth provide `$rootScope.user` as the current user and it can be used in controllers.
But I still don't know how to provide related data to user object, fortunately found workaround for my needs.